# Is there a math formula computing the size of the video given its video and audio information?

Tags: video

[image]

I have a short video of length 11s in mp4 format. As you can see from the screenshot, it is 1080 by 1920 with Data rate 2097 kbps and total bitrade 2208 kbps. Frame rate is 30.00 fps.

The audio bit rate is 111 kbps with two stereo channels and the audio sample rate is 44.100 kHz.

> Question: how to compute the size of my video based on the information above?

Observation: Total bitrate = (video) Data rate + (audio) Bit rate = 2097 + 111 = 2208

But I guess 2208kbps * 11s = 24288 kb, while my video size is much bigger, see [image]

**What goes wrong here? Or am I using the wrong formula?**

Comment: What makes you say that “my video size is much bigger”? 24288 kb = 24,288,000 bits = 3,046,000 bytes quite closely matches your given file size (give or take rounding errors, and possibly some headers whose size is not accounted for).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Sorry I took bytes there as bits... there is a 8-times difference...